# Trouble turning the screen horizontally in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

first of all I will try to explain this problem by using google translate because I do not know English well.

I'm trying to post my screen recording on my webcam with ffmpeg. My screen is reversed horizontally in a way that I don't understand when I do this. I will need help for this.

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 60 -s 1366x768 -i :0+0,0 -vf hflip -vf scale=1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video50
```

I did a few researches on the internet to fix this. A few parameters like -vf vflip are used, but I have tried almost all of them.
But I couldn't get any results.

Screenshot:
[image]

I hope a solution will be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All filters should be in one filtergraph.

`-vf hflip -vf scale=1920x1080`  ==>  `-vf "hflip,scale=1920x1080"`